# Как сделать, чтобы при запросе выдавались все ответы, а не только один?

Tags: prolog

Мой код:

```
parent(pamela, bob).
parent(tom, bob).
parent(tom, liz).
parent(bob, ann).
parent(bob, patricia).
parent(patricia, jim).
grandparent(X, Y) :- parent(X, Z), parent(Z, Y).

% Кто прародители Патриции?
query(X) :- grandparent(X, patricia).
```

В онлайн трансляторе ([ссылка](https://rextester.com/l/prolog_online_compiler)) делаю запрос:

```
query(X).
```

В ответ получаю:

```
X = pamela
```

Потерян tom. Как сделать, чтобы вывело всех грандпарентов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляйте ,write(X),nl,fail. в конец запроса.

```
parent(pamela, bob).
parent(tom, bob).
parent(tom, liz).
parent(bob, ann).
parent(bob, patricia).
parent(patricia, jim).
grandparent(X, Y) :- parent(X, Z), parent(Z, Y).

% Кто прародители Патриции?
query(X) :- grandparent(X, patricia),write(X),nl,fail.
```

query(X). выдаёт

pamela
tom
false.

Answer (score 3):

В процессе диалога с машиной вывода Prolog следующее найденное решение можно получить передав символ `;`. в данном редакторе в поле ввода нужно поставить `;` на следующей строчке в поле ввода и заново запустить вывод, нажав на кнопку `Run it [F8]`. Таким образом, если поле ввода будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
query(X).
;
;
```

то ответом системы будет

```
X = pamela X = tom false.
```

В первый раз будет найден результат `pamela`, во второй раз `tom`, в третий раз новое решение найдено не будет и пролог ответит `false`.

Часто в задаче требуется найти все возможные решения не в процессе диалога с системой, а непосредственно в процессе вывода. В таком случае используется один из встроенных предикатов `bagof`, `setof` или `findall`.

Предикат `bagof(X, P, L)` формирует список `L`, состоящий из всех объектов `X`, для которых `P` истинно. То есть, если в данном примере спросить

```
bagof(GParent, grandparent(GParent, patricia), Result).
```

ответом будет

```
Result = [pamela, tom].
```

Но если не указывать точное значение `patricia`, то Prolog будет находить все пары решений и формировать соответствующие списки. На вопрос

```
bagof(GParent, grandparent(GParent, Child), Result).
;
;
```

Получим ответ

```
Child = ann,
Result = [pamela, tom] Child = jim,
Result = [bob] Child = patricia,
Result = [pamela, tom].
```

в SWI-Prolog этот же ответ будет более нагляден:

```
?- bagof(GParent, grandparent(GParent, Child), Result).    
Child = ann,
Result = [pamela, tom];
Child = jim,
Result = [bob];
Child = patricia,
Result = [pamela, tom].
```

---

Предикат `setof` аналогичен `bagof`, но результирующий список будет упорядочен и не будет содержать дубликаты, если они есть. Немного изменим исходный пример, чтобы увидеть разницу между ними (поменяем местами первые два предиката):

```
parent(tom, bob).
parent(pamela, bob).
parent(tom, liz).
parent(bob, ann).
parent(bob, patricia).
parent(patricia, jim).
grandparent(X, Y) :- parent(X, Z), parent(Z, Y).
```

тогда

```
bagof(GParent, grandparent(GParent, Child), Result).
;
;
```

выводит результат

```
Child = ann,
Result = [tom, pamela] Child = jim,
Result = [bob] Child = patricia,
Result = [tom, pamela].
```

в первом списке `tom` и `pamela` расположены не в алфавитном порядке, но

```
setof(GParent, grandparent(GParent, Child), Result).
;
;
```

выводит

```
Child = ann,
Result = [pamela, tom] Child = jim,
Result = [bob] Child = patricia,
Result = [pamela, tom].
```

---

Предикат `findall(X, P, L)` формирует список `L` из всех `X`, для которых может быть выведена цель `P`. при этом список `L` может содержать дубликаты. Запрос

```
findall(GParent, grandparent(GParent, Child), Result).
```

на исходном примере из вопроса выведет

```
Result = [pamela, pamela, tom, tom, bob].
```

если вместо переменной `Child` задать точное значение, то разницы между `bagof` и `findall` нет (SWI-Prolog, в интерпретаторе retexter, нужно удалить приглашение `?-`)

```
?- findall(GParent, grandparent(GParent, patricia), Result).
Result = [pamela, tom].
```

---

Если нужно получить список, эквивалентный списку `L` предиката `findall`, но не содержащий повторяющиеся элементы, можно воспользоваться операцией `^` в предикате `setof(X, P, L)`. данная операция сообщает Prolog, что нас не интересует значение одной из переменных, входящих в состав цели `P` (SWI-Prolog, в интерпретаторе retexter, нужно удалить приглашение `?-`):

```
?- setof(GParent, Child ^ grandparent(GParent, Child), Result).
Result = [bob, pamela, tom].
```